# Tailwind resolving to wrong height

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I'm trying to learn tailwind. I set up an example project with extremely simple html, so hopefully this will be very easy for someone to figure out. I created a green box and set the height and width to 52px, but the box is much bigger - 208px by 208px. The generated CSS shows that the class `h-52` resolves to `13rem` instead of `52px`, (and the same for width).

If anyone knows how to  fix this issue please let me know.. Below are the relevant files.

The file structure of my project is as follows:

```
tailwind
  build
    css
      styles.css
    index.html
  src
    input.css
  tailwind.config.js
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Tailwind Experiment</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="bg-emerald-500 w-52 h-52"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Generated CSS

```
...

.h-52 {
  height: 13rem;
}

.w-52 {
  width: 13rem;
}

...
```

input.css (the starting CSS that's getting compiled into styles.css)

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./build/*.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

And I use this command to compile the necessary css: `npx tailwindcss -i ./src/input.css -o ./build/css/style.css --watch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/height) that indeed by default, `h-52` resolves to `13rem`. To have `h-52` resolve to `52px`, you'd need to customize your Tailwind configuration like:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./build/*.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        52: '52px',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

You can do this for `width` too:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ['./build/*.html'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        52: '52px',
      },
      width: {
        52: '52px',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Live example using the Tailwind CDN:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      height: {
        52: '52px',
      },
      width: {
        52: '52px',
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.5"></script>

<div class="bg-emerald-500 w-52 h-52"></div>
```

Comment: I guess that answers it! I misread the docs, thinking that "h-0   -->  height: 0px;" meant any `h-` width any numerical value would evaluate to `height: ` that number. I still don't understand why it's like this (it seems like the `h-` class will always be a fourth of the number in the class name, why?), but maybe someone else can chime in...